# Crate Common Crawl Example not working

Tags: java, sql, crate, common-crawl, nosql

I am trying to use this example of Crate with Common Crawl: https://github.com/crate/crate-commoncrawl
I have setup the Crate and even created the table schema using the instructions from the example.
I am accessing CRATE using the URL: `http://localhost:4200/_plugin/crate-admin`as I am working on my own system.

The only issue that I facing is the with the `COPY`. Let me show you that line:

```
COPY commoncrawl FROM 'ccrawl://cr8.is/1WSiodP';
```

It is triggering unknown exceptions.
Here is the error and the trace of the error:

```
COPY ERROR (0.000 sec)
Error!

SQLActionException[MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ccrawl]
```

Error Trace:

```
SQLActionException: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR 5000 MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ccrawl
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1089)
    at io.crate.operation.collect.files.URLFileInput.getStream(URLFileInput.java:52)
    at io.crate.operation.collect.files.FileReadingCollector.readLines(FileReadingCollector.java:228)
    at io.crate.operation.collect.files.FileReadingCollector.doCollect(FileReadingCollector.java:205)
    at io.crate.operation.collect.MapSideDataCollectOperation$1$1.run(MapSideDataCollectOperation.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 operating system.
Here is the image of teh error:
[image: Crate issue image]
Kindly, help me. I am not able to understand the problem. do share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the crate-commoncrawl plugin was not installed correctly. See https://github.com/crate/crate-commoncrawl#build--install.

Comment: I have tried these steps too. But I do not know what is the problem. I have built the jar and copied it to the plugin folder of CRATE. but I don't know what is the problem.. Kindly let me know if I am wrong. I have used the link as `http://localhost:4200/_plugin/crate-admin` as I am working on my system. I would like to know whether this is the right url or not...

Comment: did you check crate's startup logs if the ccrawl plugin is listed under the loaded plugins? if not, installation seems not to work, otherwise plugin seems to be broken. I'd open a issue in both cases at https://github.com/crate/crate-commoncrawl with detailed information (e.g. log ouput, steps to reproduce etc)

Comment: Sure. I look forward to hear from you Sebastian. I would like to know why this problem occurred. Do keep updating. Thankx